# Showing only value corresponding to the first character that read from file

Tags: vhdl

I have written a code to read text and to write the same text to the other text file and i want to convert each character read from the input text to an corresponding binary value. And the reading and writing text perfectly worked but the problem is it is showing only the value corresponding to the first character in the text. Please give me the idea where i am doing the mistake. Here's my code:

```
 library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use std.textio.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity asconvbin is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           d : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0));

end asconvbin;

architecture Behavioral of asconvbin is

begin
process(clk)
 variable OUTLINE : LINE;
      file FILEOUT : TEXT is OUT "outputfile.txt";
      --Input variables
            variable inline:line;
            variable char:character; 
            variable end_of_line:boolean;
            file myfile:text is "myfile.txt";
        variable k:integer;
begin
if rising_edge(clk) then

    while not endfile(myfile) loop
       readline(myfile,inline);     
         k:=inline'high;

        end_of_line := true;
        while end_of_line loop
         read(inline,char,end_of_line);

for i in k downto 0 loop

if char='A' then d<="01000000";
elsif char='B' then d<="01000001";
elsif char='C' then d<="01000010";
elsif char='D' then d<="01000011";
elsif char='E' then d<="01000100";
elsif char='F' then d<="01000101";
elsif char='G' then d<="01000110";
elsif char='H' then d<="01000111";
elsif char='I' then d<="01001000";
elsif char='J' then d<="01001001";
elsif char='K' then d<="01001010";
elsif char='L' then d<="01001011";
elsif char='M' then d<="01001100";
elsif char='N' then d<="01001101";
elsif char='O' then d<="01001110";
elsif char='P' then d<="01001111";
elsif char='Q' then d<="01010000";
elsif char='R' then d<="01010001";
elsif char='S' then d<="01010010";
elsif char='T' then d<="01010011";
elsif char='U' then d<="01010100";
elsif char='V' then d<="01010101";
elsif char='W' then d<="01010110";
elsif char='X' then d<="01010111";
elsif char='Y' then d<="01011000";
elsif char='Z' then d<="01011001";
else null;

             end if;
             k:=k-1;
end loop;

     if end_of_line then 
            WRITE(OUTLINE,char);
          end if;
    end loop;
end loop;
WRITELINE(FILEOUT, OUTLINE); 

end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: If you were wiling to have actual ISO-8859-1 values for each character (which are compatible with ASCII, etc.) and `std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(character'POS('A'),8) ) = "01000001"`, instead of `x"40"`, you could use the left expression in the preceeding conditionto convert to binary values.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for `d` only outputting value for first character, is that `k` is
decremented in the `for i in k downto 0 loop` with `k := k-1`, thus resulting
in `k` being -1 for second character from the input file, and the range is then
`for i in -1 downto 0 loop`, which is a null range, thus resulting in the loop
being skipped, whereby no subsequent assigns to `d` are made.  Code cooked down:

```
while not endfile(myfile) loop
  readline(myfile, inline);
  k := inline'high;
  ...
  while end_of_line loop
    ...
    for i in k downto 0 loop
      if char = 'A' then d    <= "01000000";
      ...
      end if;
      k := k-1;
    end loop;
    ...
  end loop;
end loop;
```

An alternative way to convert `char` to a `std_logic_vector` is:

```
d <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(character'pos(char), d'length));
```

Comment: then how to get the value corresponding to the character that read ?